# ¿Cómo eliminar CSS que bloquea el renderizado si viene de una CDN?

Tags: html5, enlace

Al hacerle auditorias a mi página con PageSpeed me saltan alertas en las que me dice "Elimina los recursos que bloqueen el renderizado", he estado revisando el problema y en mis css estamos "ok" el problema esta en los CDN que he utilizado (Bootstrap y boxicon) como puedo resolver esto, llamadas a hojas de estilo donde no soy propietario, también investigando encontré que puedo usar async rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheets' en mis link pero no se si esto sean buenas practicas. ¿Alguna recomendación? anexo parte de mi HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>
  </title>
  <link async rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheets'""
    integrity="sha384-tKLJeE1ALTUwtXlaGjJYM3sejfssWdAaWR2s97axw4xkiAdMzQjtOjgcyw0Y50KU" crossorigin="anonymous" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheets'">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheets'">
</head>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Siempre tienes la opción de descargar esos css y agregarlos a tu proyecto sin usar cdn

Comment: Hola Oscar gracias por tu comentario, lo que pasa es que ya no quiero  hacer más pesado mi proyecto por eso estoy usando CDN.

Comment: El peso de tu proyecto puede que se incremente un poco, pero con esto harás que mejore el tiempo de carga (además de solucionar tu problema)

Comment: He decidido tenerlos en el servidor Oscar tal como me recomendaste y la verdad es que no agrego mucho peso al proyecto, gracias por tu respuesta.